# Using Regex How to capture a pattern line and lines around it in C#?

Tags: c#, regex, text

I have 2 Issues to be resolved in this Regex.

1- I have a pattern to identify.

Example:- **He studied from April 2011- 2014** (Pattern to be identified)

In the above example April 2011 is the reference to identify this line from a text of hundreds of lines. 
Note: April 2011 can be written in different ways like Apr 2011, 04/2011. So my regex should be such that i can capture this irrespective of how ever it is written.

2. And then top and bottom lines from that pattern are to be captured/extracted along with the pattern. Here is the below example

Example:-

*Karthick is a good student* (line on top of the pattern)

**He studied from April 2011- 2014** (Pattern)

*He was good at academics.* (Line below the pattern)

After being able to identify the 1st pattern, i would like to extract the above and below line from that pattern.

Comment: Post your code. Also does it have to be a regex? A for loop over each lines scanning for the pattern will be simple.

Comment: Have you made an attempt at creating the code? There is plenty of online resources for [learning](http://www.regexr.com/)

Comment: *irrespective of how ever it is written* ? is not an option when it comes to Regular Expressions. You should atleast provide a set of values that you wish to match using Regex.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the below regex and get the line 1 from group index 1 and line 2 from index 2.

```
@"(.*)\n.*\b(?:Apr(?:il)? |04/)2011.*\n(.*)"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nY2tE8/1)

`(?:Apr(?:il)? |04/)` would match `Apr` or `April` or `04/`

Comment: Hey Avinash, Thanks for your answer, it worked out. But since i'm doing in C#, it is not accepting *. I'm getting an error. * is not being accepted.